# Jenkins geting result from python call

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, jenkins

My jenkins pipeline needs some configuration data from a config.ini file that I parse with pythons configparser.

The python function I call from Jenkins both prints and returns a string with the values I need.
But the output I manage to capture in Jenkins seems to be the actual command to python and not the python output.

Obviously I'm missing something and a push in the right direction would be very appreciated.
Working on Windows but I believe that I might be able to extrapolate from a linux solution.

I have this pipeline stage:

```
stage('Get DB Config'){
    environment {
        cmd = 'python -c "from common.utils import utils; utils.get_db_settings()"'
    db = ''
    }
    steps {
    dir('tests/AgdaPyTests')
    db = bat(script: "${cmd}", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
    bat "echo ${db}"
}
```

Output:
<path> -c "from common.utils import utils; utils.get_db_settings()" 1>python

Expected:
Either the returned output from the python script or the printed output from the python script.

What it looks now I have managed to capture the actual call and not the output.

Note: I had trouble copying the actual code and result from test machine so this is manually copied by typing so there might be typos in the code example.

Comment: Can be closed, error was in a small typo to the Python function that was still syntactically correct but did not get the correct result.